# List Comprehension with IF clause

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why below code is not working with IF condition in list comprehension? "Contents" does not exist in "response" to it should return empty list.

```
response={"Contents1" : [ {"a" : 1, "b" : 1},{"a" : 2, "b" : 2},{"a" : 3, "b" : 3 } ] }
lst=[item["a"] for item in response["Contents"] if "Contents" in response]
print(lst)
```

KeyError: 'Contents'

Below works fine and does not print any output as "Contents" does not exist in "response"

```
if "Contents" in response:
    for item in response["Contents"]:
    print(item["a"])
```

Comment: I think the if clause is executed for every item in the iterable i.e. the iterable has to be loaded first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comprehension is still trying to access a dictionary with a non-existent key. You could do the following instead:

```
[item["a"] for k in response for item in response[k] if k == "Contents"]
```

Comment: Thanks it did work. Can you please provide simple code of how its working? Are we running for loop two times?

Comment: Yes, we are basically running a nested for-loop. A list comprehension is basically syntactic sugar for a loop construct.